# Framework version mismatch in ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

While I'm creating ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) projects in VS 2017 with .NET Framework version 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2, the .csproj file has the below entry only.

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
 <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The TargetFramework value is net452 only. Is it mean the application targets .NET 4.5.2? If yes, then you do we select the framework version while creating the project. If not, then where can I find the version of the application in the project files anywhere?

Note: But if I select .NET 4.6 or 4.6.1, its showing TargetFramework as net46 and net461 respectively in the .csproj file.

[image]

Comment: What is main the question?  Is it mean the application targets .NET 4.5.2? So, then asnwer is Yes! Can I find the version of the application in the project files anywhere? Yes, as you described in .csproj file

Comment: The question is, even if I select 4.5 or 4.5.1 in the new project dialog and create the project, the project targets 4.5.2 only. If I see the properties tab, the Target Framework value is .NET 4.5.2.